# Import error - Cannot import name x from y

Tags: python, class, import

Im having trouble importing a class on a python module.

Here are my directory structure:

```
TestMap
  +lib
    +vendors
      +testing
       - _init.py
       - products.py
    - _init_py.
    - notifications.py
    - scraper.py
    - utils.py
  -main.py
```

And I'm starting on `scraper.py` and trying to get functions on products.py which is `vendors -> testing -> products.py`

```
from .vendors.testing.products import TestProducts
```

and what I am trying to do is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TestProducts' from 'lib.vendors.testing.products' (C:\Users\Annoynmous\Desktop\TestMap\lib\vendors\testing\products.py)
```

and inside the products.py the class name is:

```
class TestProducts():
```

and I cant get a grip what I am actually doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in  **scraper.py**

```
from vendors.testing.products import TestProducts
```

Or

```
import vendors.testing.products as product 
class scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.product = product.TestProducts()
```

Use `self.product` to access any function of TestProducts inside the class scraper.

Comment: The first line does say that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vendors'`

Comment: `print(sys.path)` to check whether your directory path included or not. If not `sys.path.insert(0,"Path/to/lib directory/")`

Comment: Doing sys.path, I can see the folder beginning. in this case just C://Users//Annoymous//Desktop//TestMap and then different python files

Comment: that means you need to import from lib i.e. `import lib.vendors.testing.products as product `

Comment: Hmm, I think I am getting an error which I do have but I am not sure whats the reason of it: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'`

Comment: use `__init__(self)`, it seems you need to brush up your Python OOPs concept

Comment: Ohhh its what happens when you program way too much :( But it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `pythonpath` to set the source directory in your project:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/somepath/TestMap
```

and import the modules from that source path

```
from lib.vendors.testing.products import TestProducts
```

Or use `__init__.py` file to define your internal module directory and import the module with direct module name.

Comment: Hey, I am not sure where to add the first row `export`? Is it inside a .py file or? but isnt it possible to soehow call the function the way I am trying to?

Comment: In your termian, it will define `pythonpath` and you will be able import modules from that path.